# Adding carriage return in a map instruction in gVim

Tags: vim, windows-7

After copying my .vimrc file over to windows I noticed there were a lot of problems. I fixed most of them, but I noticed anything with a `<CR>` command in it does not work. I just get a "ding" sound.

Here is an example of one command which causes no errors, but doesn't do what it's supposed to. I just get the ding sound

```
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>
```

Am I supposed to use something instead fo `<CR>`? Note, I did *google it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your config (well, you probably don't need the duplicate `mapleader` definition). I can only imagine problems when you have `<CR>` mapped in command-line mode. For this reason, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion. To check for problems with mapleader, try invoking via the original leader, i.e. <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>. Also, you can check for your mapping (not being overwritten / cleared) via `:verbose nmap <Leader>w`.